# На разных API то показывается заголовок, то нет, как исправить?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

На разных API то показывается заголовок, то нет, как исправить?
При сборке использовал Android Studio 1.4.1, Empty Activity, 
Минимум SDK API 9 2.3

[image: Нет заголовка при API 17]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В стили какие то изменения вносили?

Comment: Стили не редактировались, стиль "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная от версии sdk 21 и выше, рекомендовано использовать такое элемент как [Toolbar](http://habrahabr.ru/post/241479/). Он полностью заменяет ActionBar. Можно настроить тему в Вашем случае, или же перейти на Toolbar соответственно запретив отображать ActionBar `<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`.